# "temporary value dropped while borrowed" with HashMap<&str, &dyn Fn(&str) -> bool>

Tags: rust, closures, lifetime, borrow-checker, trait-objects

I have a `HashMap` of strings to functions. From my understanding the `&dyn Fn(&str) -> bool` is necessary since I want to use both functions and closures, however I'm getting this compile error:

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> src/test.rs:22:26
   |
22 |     checks.insert("k3", &|i| cached_regex.is_match(i));
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   |                          |
   |                          creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
...
27 |         match checks.get(kvp[0]) {
   |               ------ borrow later used here
   |
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
```

Example code:

```rust
use regex::Regex;
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(run_checks("k1:test, k3:1234"), true);
    assert_eq!(run_checks("k1:test, k3:12345"), false);
    assert_eq!(run_checks("k1:test, k2:test2"), true);
}

fn specific_check(i: &str) -> bool { i == "test" }

fn run_checks(input: &str) -> bool {
    let cached_regex = Regex::new(r"^\d{4}$").unwrap();

    let mut checks: HashMap<&str, &dyn Fn(&str) -> bool> = HashMap::new();
    checks.insert("k1", &specific_check);
    checks.insert("k2", &|i| i == "test2");

    // Not working
    checks.insert("k3", &|i| cached_regex.is_match(i));

    for kvp_pair in input.split(",") {
        let kvp: Vec<&str> = kvp_pair.trim().split(":").collect();

        match checks.get(kvp[0]) {
            Some(check) => {
                if !check(kvp[1]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            None => return false,
        }
    }

    true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straight-forward way to solve this problem is to `Box` the `dyn Fn(&str) -> bool` trait objects. Fixed working example:

```rust
use regex::Regex;
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(run_checks("k1:test, k3:1234"), true);
    assert_eq!(run_checks("k1:test, k3:12345"), false);
    assert_eq!(run_checks("k1:test, k2:test2"), true);
}

fn specific_check(i: &str) -> bool { i == "test" }

fn run_checks(input: &str) -> bool {
    let cached_regex = Regex::new(r"^\d{4}$").unwrap();

    let mut checks: HashMap<&str, Box<dyn Fn(&str) -> bool>> = HashMap::new();
    checks.insert("k1", Box::new(specific_check));
    checks.insert("k2", Box::new(|i| i == "test2"));
    
    // now works
    checks.insert("k3", Box::new(|i| cached_regex.is_match(i)));

    for kvp_pair in input.split(",") {
        let kvp: Vec<&str> = kvp_pair.trim().split(":").collect();

        match checks.get(kvp[0]) {
            Some(check) => {
                if !check(kvp[1]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            None => return false,
        }
    }

    true
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f3c46eba1365b6fea79f25d07ec1024c)

---

**Detailed explanation behind solution**

The type annotation in this line is incomplete since the lifetimes of the references and of the trait object itself are omitted:

```rust
let mut checks: HashMap<&str, &dyn Fn(&str) -> bool> = HashMap::new();
```

Given what keys and values you insert into `checks` Rust infers the complete type of `checks` to be `HashMap<&'static str, &'static (dyn for<'a> Fn(&'a str) -> bool + 'static)>`. The first two inserts match this type signature but the final third one does not. The value used in the third insert has the type `&'static (dyn for<'a> Fn(&'a str) -> bool + 'b)` where `'b` represents the lifetime of the captured `cached_regex` variable. The reason Rust throws a compiler error is because it's invalid to create a `'static` reference to some type with a non-`'static` lifetime since it would be possible for the reference to become invalidated. Boxing the trait object avoids this issue since we no longer have to create a `'static` reference to it, therefore there's no longer the requirement that the trait object itself needs to live for `'static` and the final third insert can be safely made.

Comment: Can you explain why it is necessary to box in the last case with "k3", but not at "k2"?